# Most elegant way to convert string array into a dictionary of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

Is there a built-in function for converting a string array into a dictionary of strings or do you need to do a loop here?

Comment: Depends on the structure you want all in all. You will end up with a loop though, no matter how you look at it.

Comment: There will always be a loop somewhere, but LINQ allows you to hide it - i.e. you don't need to have the loop in *your* code.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Assuming you're using .NET 3.5, you can turn any sequence (i.e. `IEnumerable<T>`) into a dictionary:

```
var dictionary = sequence.ToDictionary(item => item.Key,
                                       item => item.Value)
```

where `Key` and `Value` are the appropriate properties you want to act as the key and value. You can specify just one projection which is used for the key, if the item itself is the value you want.

So for example, if you wanted to map the upper case version of each string to the original, you could use:

```
var dictionary = strings.ToDictionary(x => x.ToUpper());
```

In your case, what do you want the keys and values to be?

If you actually just want a *set* (which you can check to see if it contains a particular string, for example), you can use:

```
var words = new HashSet<string>(listOfStrings);
```

Comment: That risc is always there, unless you check before for duplicate keys.

Comment: @Dykam: Indeed. If you want to handle duplicates, you potentially want `ToLookup` instead. Hopefully we'll find out more if the OP explains what they're really trying to do.

Comment: Cool! What if I had a string array of keys and a string array of values of the same length? Can Linq help me then?

Comment: @Hamish: I'd probably handle that with Zip personally, but there are various ways you *could* do it.

Comment: see shA.t 's post below.   you really need IndexOf for the key in the dictionary,  I agree with shA.t that what people are looking for is a Dictionary<int,string>, where the key is the old array index.

Comment: @mike: No, `IndexOf` would be a bad idea. If the aim is to create a `Dictionary<int, string>` I'd use `array.Select((value, index) => new { value, index }).ToDictionary(pair => pair.index, pair => pair.value);` Otherwise, if there are multiple identical strings in the array, you'd fail due to non-unique keys.

Comment: John Skeet: YES! IndexOf would be a bad idea, of course.   I like the solution that you provide in  your comment.   @shA.t's corrected answer using your comment is equally correct.  However, unless I am missing something, your posted/accepted answer is not suitable for "for converting a string array into a dictionary of strings" as leora asks.

Comment: @mike: Yes it is. It's creating a dictionary. The OP never specified what kind of dictionary - these days the question would have been closed as being unclear. My answer clearly helped the OP enough though, given that they accepted it - I think they're in a better position to know what's suitable than you are.

Comment: John Skeet: My confusion is with the inputs, not the output. The OP asks to convert "a string array", and you give an example of converting "any sequence (i.e. IEnumerable<T>)", and I am unclear how you propose to convert a string[] into IEnumerable, as your example sequence.ToDictionary(item => item.Key,
                                       item => item.Value) would certanly not work if sequence (the input) was a string array.

Comment: @mike: A `string[]` is an `IEnumerable<string>`, so it's a matter of deciding exactly what you want those lambda expressions to do. The OP didn't say what they wanted the keys/values to be, so I preferred to leave it somewhat general - with a specific example later, note - rather than *assuming* that the OP wanted it to be from the array index (at which point, why use a dictionary at all?). As I say, the OP seemed to be happy enough 7 years ago, so I really don't think it's worth second-guessing them now.

Answer (score 21):

You can use LINQ to do this, but the question that Andrew asks should be answered first (what are your keys and values):

```
using System.Linq;

string[] myArray = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
myArray.ToDictionary(key => key, value => value);
```

The result is a dictionary like this:

```
A -> A
B -> B
C -> C
```

Answer (score 15):

IMO, When we say an `Array` we are talking about a list of values that we can get a value with calling its index (value => array[index]), So a correct dictionary is a dictionary with a key of index.

And with thanks to @John Skeet, the proper way to achieve that is:

```
var dictionary = array
    .Select((v, i) => new {Key = i, Value = v})
    .ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Value);
```

---

Another way is to use an extension method like this:

```
public static Dictionary<int, T> ToDictionary<T>(this IEnumerable<T> array)
{
    return array
        .Select((v, i) => new {Key = i, Value = v})
        .ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Value);
}
```

Comment: This will a) be inefficient; b) fail if the same value occurs more than once in the array. You could use the `Select` overload which provides the index as well, to do this more efficiently and reliably.

Comment: Thanks, and I edit the code as you referenced to use `Select` ;).

Answer (score 5):

If you need a dictionary without values, you might need a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx):

```
var hashset = new HashSet<string>(stringsArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean?

A dictionary is a hash, where keys map to values.

What are your keys and what are your values?

```
foreach(var entry in myStringArray)
    myDictionary.Add(????, entry);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that the question has to do with arrays where the keys and values alternate.  I ran into this problem when trying to convert redis protocol to a dictionary.

```
private Dictionary<T, T> ListToDictionary<T>(IEnumerable<T> a)
{
    var keys = a.Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 0);
    var values = a.Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 1);
    return keys
        .Zip(values, (k, v) => new KeyValuePair<T, T>(k, v))
        .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            Dictionary<int, string> dictionaryTest = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < testArray.Length; i++)
            {
                dictionaryTest.Add(i, testArray[i]);
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> item in dictionaryTest)
            {


                Console.WriteLine("Array Position {0} and Position Value {1}",item.Key,item.Value.ToString()); 
            }
```

Comment: Don't just blurt out code! Adding some text to describe how this solution best answers the question will improve the long-term value of the answer and help to prevent it from being deleted during review.

Comment: This was just what I needed, thank you! Could not think.

Answer (score 0):

The Question is not very clear, but Yes you can convert a string to `Dictionary` provided the string is delimited with some characters to support `Dictionary<Key,Value>` pair

So if a string is like  `a=first;b=second;c=third;d=fourth` you can split it first based on `;` then on `=` to create a `Dictionary<string,string>` the below extension method does the same

```cs
public static Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(this string stringData, char propertyDelimiter = ';', char keyValueDelimiter = '=')
{
    Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Array.ForEach<string>(stringData.Split(propertyDelimiter), s =>
        {
            if(s != null && s.Length != 0)
                keyValuePairs.Add(s.Split(keyValueDelimiter)[0], s.Split(keyValueDelimiter)[1]);
        });

    return keyValuePairs;
}
```

and can use it like

```cs
var myDictionary = "a=first;b=second;c=third;d=fourth".ToDictionary();
```

since the default parameter is `;` & `=` for the extension method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary from an `IEnumerable<T>`, including an array, via:

```csharp
var dictionary = myEnumerable.ToDictionary(element => element.Key,
                                           element => element.Value)
```

where `Key` and `Value` are the key and value you want to store in each dictionary element. Available in .NET Framework 3.5+/.NET Core 1.0+/.NET 5.0+. [Official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary)

If you want the dictionary *values* to be the elements from the original enumerable:

```csharp
   var dictionary = myEnumerable.ToDictionary(element => element.Key)
```

If you only need high-performance set operations, you may be able to use:

```csharp
var words = new HashSet<string>(listOfStrings);
```

In simple terms, the HashSet class can be thought of as a Dictionary<TKey,TValue> collection without values. [Official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1)

(Note that a 'sequence' in an [entirely unrelated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activities.statements.sequence) object.
Originally submitted an existing answer edit but it was rejected by the author so posting separately, including with links to the official Microsoft documentation.)