# Convert Colon Separated String to a Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string `Number1.pdf:Alpha1.pdf; Number2.pdf:Alpha2.pdf; Number3.pdf:Alpha3.pdf;` and I would like get it converted to a Dictionary.

```
Ditionary<Number1,Alpha1> etc.
```

I looked for examples online and I found most of them converting Dictionary to String.Can someone help me ?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1385432/961695

Comment: Would that string happen to be part of a larger JSON string?

Comment: See my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56342800/3057246

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with LINQ:

```
var input = "Number1.pdf:Alpha1.pdf; Number2.pdf:Alpha2.pdf; Number3.pdf:Alpha3.pdf;";

var items = input.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var result = items.Select(x => x.Split(':'))
                  .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Split('.').First().Trim(),
                                x => x[1].Split('.').First().Trim());
```

It will skip `.pdf` at the end of both keys and values (as described in question).

```
foreach (var i in result)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

prints

```
[Number1, Alpha1]
[Number2, Alpha2]
[Number3, Alpha3]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string s = "Number1.pdf:Alpha1.pdf; Number2.pdf:Alpha2.pdf; Number3.pdf:Alpha3.pdf;";
var names = s.Replace(".pdf","")
            .Split(";".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
            .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);
```