# How to convert an array to dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

I have an array with two values eg. `[Name,Anu]`.

I want to convert this array to dictionary in which the key is `"Name"` and value as `"Anu"`. Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385421/most-elegant-way-to-convert-string-array-into-a-dictionary-of-strings

Comment: Please see the answer there https://stackoverflow.com/a/56342800/3057246

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with *Linq*

```
var array = new (string, string)[12];
var result = array.ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2);
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DRqOJe)

---

**Additional Resources**

[ToDictionary(IEnumerable, Func)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__)

> Creates a Dictionary from an IEnumerable according to
>   a specified key selector function.

Answer (score 1):

If I take your question literally, you just want

```
input = new string [] { "Name", "Anu" };
var output = new Dictionary<string,string>();
output.Add(input[0], input[1]);
```

Or

```
input = new string [] { "Name", "Anu" };
var output = new Dictionary<string,string>
{
    { input[0], input[1] }
};
```